# SpringBoot - @Configuration creates a singleton bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In SpringBoot Application, when a bean is created inside a class annotated with @Configuration, is it singleton? Or is it created for each request. For example, in the below code, Is clientBean singleton?

```
@Configuration(name = "clientBean")
class StarupConfiguration {
 @Bean
 fun ApiServiceClient(): IApiServiceClient {
        return new ApiServiceClient();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `@Bean` produces a **singleton** bean to be managed by the Spring Container.

If you want to modify this behaviour, you can mark the method with `@Scope` to switch from singleton to any other scope you want.

```java
 @Bean
 @Scope("prototype")
 public MyBean myBean() {
     return new MyBean();
 }
```

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's a singleton. Look at the [@Scope annotation documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html#scopeName--) to see how to modify that behavior. It also confirms that singleton is the default scope.