# How to create immutable and singleton class in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired, lombok

I have a person model class that needs to be immutable and singleton. I need to autowire from my service class but getting an error.

So is there any way to create a singleton immutable class in spring boot? where i can set values in person (via autowire) and use the same in the entire application.

I have just started learning spring-boot. I searched on google and found the solution with Lombok but somehow it didn't work for me.

My person model :

```
    @Value
    @Builder
    @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE) 
    @Component
    public final class Person {
        private final String firstName;
        private final String lastName;
    }


//My service class
@Component
public class ArgumentReadingService {
    
    @Autowired
    Person person;
    
    public void readArguments() {
        
        person = Person.builder().firstName("Hello").build();
        
        System.out.println("name : "+person.getFirstName());
        
    }
```

Error :

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-03-10 17:52:29.197 ERROR 8824 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'person' defined in file [C:\Users\User\Desktop\WorkSpace\Orion.Strat1.bidAsk_Stp\target\classes\orion\model\Person.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [orion.model.Person]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: orion.model.Person.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1316) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) [spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) [spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) [spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) [spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.orion.Application.main(Application.java:20) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [orion.model.Person]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: orion.model.Person.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: orion.model.Person.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Where are you expecting Spring to get the first and last name from, for Person? Also, you have specified the constructor as private. Spring might be able to get around that with reflection, but it could easily be the case it will ignore any private constructors. Definitely a code smell either way, because you won't be able to write a unit test for it should you want to.

Comment: Model classes are the exact thing that should _not_ be a singleton; they're literally the specific per-request data.

Comment: A Builder pattern and a Singleton aren't exactly the same. Making your constructor private doesn't make it a singleton if you allow your Builder to create countless instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This configuration class and that annotation will provide you always with that Person Bean

```
@Configuration
public class ServerConfig
{

    @Bean
    private Person getPerson(){
        return new Person("name", "lastName");
    }
```

Now it will be available everywhere for autowiring.

As the comments note however, it seems strange to use a model class as a Singleton.

Comment: ServerConfig extends what?

Comment: @BabyishTank nothing corrected the answer

Answer (score -1):

Adding some more info for the readers,

Look at this question for more clarity
[SpringBoot - @Configuration creates a singleton bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58868112/springboot-configuration-creates-a-singleton-bean)